# Swap two strings using array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I'm trying to replace "e" with "E" and "E" with "e" in a string and it seems that doesn't works properly. I'm using array:

```
$original = "e and E";
$swap = array(
    "E" => "e",
    "e"  => "E");

$edited= str_replace(array_keys($swap), array_values($swap), $original);

echo $original. "<br>";
echo $edited;
```

It returns "E and E". I want to return "E and e", can you help me?

Comment: You will always have all `E` since that is the last replacement.

Comment: [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) only iterates over the input once while replacing; and is more convenient for pairing substitution letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a [gotcha](http://php.net/str_replace), this is expected behavior. You replaced all `E` with `e`, then all `e` with `E`. So the result is `E and E`.

You will need to do this in two passes, use a placeholder, or use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). As commented by **mario**, the appropriate function to *swap* strings is `strtr()`:

```
$edited = strtr($original, $swap);
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` can take an array, but it does not work as you expect. You could use it to replace for example all occurences of "e" with "E" and all of "a" with "A" but it is done *sequentially* and not at the same time. So In your code, "e and E" is first replaced to "e and e" and then to "E and E".

Do this instead:

```
$original = "e and E";
$edited = str_replace("e", "#", $original);
$edited = str_replace("E", "e", $edited);
$edited = str_replace("#", "E", $edited);
echo $original. "<br>";
echo $edited;
```

Comment: As you noted yourself, `strtr()` is a better solution. Consider what happens if `$original` has `#` in it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two passes, using temporary tokens:

```
$original = "e and E";
$swap = array(
    "E" => "$",
    "e"  => "E",
    "$" => 'e',    
);

$edited= str_replace(array_keys($swap), array_values($swap), $original);
echo $edited;
```

Comment: `strtr()` is a better solution. Consider what happens if `$original` has `$` in it?